# Mod_rewrite with multiple variables and no id

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create some mod rewrites that will have four variables and not make use of the id, currently my business pages are:

> www.mysite.com/business.php?Busid=1

what I want them to look like is:

> www.mysite.com/City/BusinessType/BusinessName-Neighborhood

Is there a way I can continue to get the page by the id (to ensure it's unique) and rewrite the URLs and not have it include the id?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you want Apache to magically remember all of the string name => ID mappings? Negative. For this, you store a field commonly referred to as a `slug` in your database. Create a unique index, and do your lookups by that rather than ID.

Comment: If you are sure that the combination city, businesstype, businessname, neighborhood is unique, you can let mod_rewrite redirecto to a PHP script that retrieves the ID based on these names. It is however easier to add a number somewhere in the URL with the id, additional to the names you use. For example: www.mysite.com/City/BusinessType/ID-BusinessName-Neighborhood

Comment: Thank you both! I'll look into both options!